# Do all players need to own Horizons to participate in multicrewing?

Tags: elite-dangerous, elite-dangerous-horizons

Elite: Dangerous 2.3 introduced the ability to invite friends to sit in seats on your ship and take on various extra roles (like auxiliary gunner and such). Do both of us need to own Horizons to do this? Or can you invite a non-Horizons player?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, multi-crewing is [Horizons-only content](https://www.elitedangerous.com/en/seasons/#season2) and requires that all participating Commanders have Horizons to take part. While using multi-crewing you also can't participate in a wing, though this is apparently due to technical limitations and not intentional division of features.

When the player you want to invite to your crew doesn't have Horizons, the option is disabled, referencing the fact that they don't have Horizons:

[image: bug report image showing crew is Horizons-only]
<sup>([source](https://forums.frontier.co.uk/showthread.php/338277-INVITE-TO-CREW-HORIZONS-ONLY))</sup>